# Getting 404 while trying to preview a newly edited office document in ngx doc viewer Angular

Tags: file-upload, azure-blob-storage, angular12, ngx-doc-viewer, document-preview

I'm working on ngx-doc-viewer in angular and when I'm trying to get a document preview of Docx file I'm getting 404 in one case.

I'm uploading my document to a blob storage and giving that blob URL for the file URL of the document.
Normally, If I upload a docx file to blob storage and using that blob URL to get the preview I'm getting the document preview properly
[When uploaded document normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLhUU.png)

But when I edit a document using wps office(not sure if it will happen with other editors also) and immediately upload that document. I'm getting 404 while it is fetching the preview. If I do the preview again after sometime It is loading fine.
[When uploading immediately edited document.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BIEL.png)

Any suggestions?

Initially I thought it was due to location Im getting it even before file is completely uploaded but It was working incase I upload a document that was not edited recently so I ruled out that case.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting 404 while it is fetching the preview

The above error occurs

- If another client deleted a container or blob before this request.
- If the specified **`blob or resource URL`** does not exist may cause [404 error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes).
- Please make sure the **`filename`** (blob name) you provided indeed exists in your container because blob name is case sensitive.
- If you are accessing through private container is one possible reason and change **`Access level to container or blob`**.

**I tried in my environment to fetch file from azure blob storage and got same error in postman:**

**Postman:**

[image]

I tried with proper **`Url+SAS-token`**, I can successfully fetch files from postman.

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure Storage Static website error - Resource not found or content doesn't exist - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56057614/azure-storage-static-website-error-resource-not-found-or-content-doesnt-exist) by Bennie van der Walt.