# "WebContentNotFound" error with azure static web

Tags: azure

I have made a storage account then enabled static website then added the html file (plus everything else i need). once everything was added into the $web i copy pasted the give url and i get a 404 error as follows:
The requested content does not exist.
HttpStatusCode: 404
ErrorCode: WebContentNotFound
RequestId : 23ac6dc2-401e-0044-7797-b2e9c5000000
TimeStamp : 2021-09-26T05:29:47.2306494Z

i have used azure before for another school project and that website worked fine. i tried uploading those files in a new storage account and they gave me the same error but the website i made 6 months ago still works. naturally i thought well if this storage account still works then i will just put the new files in here and delete this website since its not needed anymore. tried and it gave me the same error so i changed it back to the original and now i get the error with those files too. any help would be amazing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478636/azure-webcontentnotfound-on-refreshing-page-of-spa-deployed-as-azure-blob-stati

Answer (score 0):

Azure blob storage doesn’t know to route requests to /OurWebPage through our index.html it only knows to route to index.html when requests are made to the base URL as we configured the default document. This means search crawlers and anyone linking directly to a page will get this error

Here we need to use Azure CDN, with this we can configure URL rewrites.

We can create CDN resource with Standard Microsoft tier. Refer to the [blog](http://Azure%20blob%20storage%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20know%20to%20route%20requests%20to%20/OurWebPage%20through%20our%20index.html%20it%20only%20knows%20to%20route%20to%20index.html%20when%20requests%20are%20made%20to%20the%20base%20URL%20as%20we%20configured%20the%20default%20document.%20This%20means%20search%20crawlers%20and%20anyone%20linking%20directly%20to%20a%20page%20will%20get%20this%20error%20Here%20we%20need%20to%20use%20Azure%20CDN,%20with%20this%20we%20can%20configure%20URL%20rewrites.%20We%20can%20create%20CDN%20resource%20with%20Standard%20Microsoft%20tier.%20Refer%20to%20the%20blog%20for%20more%20insights.) for more insights.